# how to use wepay PHP sdk in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, payment-gateway, laravel-5

I want to use [wepay PHP sdk](https://github.com/wepay/php-sdk) in laravel 5 using composer but I didn't found any laravel package for it.

Can you please tell me me how can I do this?

Comment: Make one yourself/just use it? Laravel is just PHP...

Comment: @WouterJ how can I just use it? can you please provide me link or example

Comment: Are you asking how to download a `.php` file from GitHub and `require` it in your PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

The package is available via packagist.org - unfortunately only as a dev-master branch and with suboptimal autoloading configured (I'm trying to fix that, sent both a patch and opened an issue suggesting they tag their version).

Adding that package is basic Composer action. The classes should be automatically available within Laravel wherever you think you want to use it.